# Angular 2: Insert template after element

Tags: angular

I have the following html (simplified for illustration).

```
//removed irrelevant HTML
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let el of elements; let i = index" >
      <td>
         <button (click)="showTemplate(i, $event)">Click me {{i}}</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<template #myTemplate>
   <tr>
      <td>You have clicked a button</td>
   </tr>
</template>
```

What I would like to achieve is that when a button is clicked in a specific `tr`, the template should be inserted after that specific `tr`.

What I thought I could do is to get the templateRef using `ViewChild` and then get its node and use something like:

```
@ViewChild('myTemplate', {read: TemplateRef}) myTemplate;

showTemplate(i, event) { 
   // i would get selectedTR from the event
   selectedTR.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', this.myTemplate.elementRef.nativeElement)`
}
```

but all I get from `this.myTemplate.elementRef.nativeElement` when the function is run is

Is the method I am following the correct one? If it is, then what could possibly be wrong with my setup? If not, is there a more Angular oriented solution?

**Please note** I am using Angular 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it doesn't answer your question about inserting a template, here is how I would solve your issue:

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let el of elements; let i = index">
        <tr>
            <td>
               <button (click)="showTemplate(el)">Click me {{i}}</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngIf="el.showTemplate">
            <td>You have clicked a button</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

TS:

```
showTemplate(el: any): void {
    el.showTemplate = true;
}
```

This is effectively the same solution as your template binding though it is simpler and the template HTML (the second TR in this case) is bound to the model properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `*ngIf` and be flexible with the template content, then dynamic loading component is another way.

[Live example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sg-dynamic-table-row)

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let el of elements; let i = index" >
                    <td>
                      <row-container [element]="el"></row-container>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            `
})
export class AppComponent {

  elements = [
    {id: 1, name: "Element 1", content: "This is element 1 content"},
    {id: 2, name: "Element 2", content: "This is element 2 content"},
    {id: 3, name: "Element 3", content: "This is element 3 content"},
  ];

  constructor() { }

}
```

**row-container.component.ts**

```
import { 
  Component,
  ViewContainerRef,
  Input,
  ViewChild,
  Compiler,
  NgModule,
  Injector,
  NgModuleRef
   } from '@angular/core';

export class Element {
  constructor(
    public id: number, 
    public name: string, 
    public content: string){}
}
@Component({
  selector: 'row-container',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onRowClick()">{{element.name}} </button>
    <ng-container #vc><ng-container>
  `
})
export class RowContainerComponent {

  @Input() element: Element;

  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(
    private compiler: Compiler, 
    private injector: Injector, 
    private moduleRef: NgModuleRef<any>){
  }

  onRowClick(){
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  loadComponent(){
    this.vc.detach();

    const template = "<div><span>{{name}}</span></div>";

    const tmpComp = Component({template: template})(class{});

    const tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpComp]})(class{});

    // Compile module and all components
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
    .then((factories) =>{
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];

        const compRef = f.create(this.injector, [], null, this.moduleRef);

        compRef.instance.name = this.element.content;

        this.vc.insert(compRef.hostView);
    });
  }

}
```